# ${f \text{ is differentiable on } I \iff f_{\left|\ [a,b]\right.} \text{ is differentiable }\ \forall a,b \in I}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives

> Let $f\in \mathbb{R}^{I}$ $I$ interval of $\mathbb{R}$
>
> Show that
>
> $${f \text{ is differentiable on } I \iff  f_{\left|\ [a,b]\right.} \text{ is differentiable }\ \forall a,b \in I}$$

in my opinion if $a$ and $b$ are end of $I$ we have to study onle the left differentiable at $a$ and the right differentiable at $b$

the right derivative is defined as
$$\partial_+f(a):=\lim_{{\scriptstyle x\to a+\atop\scriptstyle x\in I}}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$

and the left derivative as
$$\partial_-f(a):=\lim_{{\scriptstyle x\to b-\atop\scriptstyle x\in I}}\frac{f(x)-f(b)}{x-b}.  $$

**Edit**

To prove the direction $\implies$ :

let $a,b \in I$ with $a<b$ since $f$ is differentiable on $I$ then f  is differentiable on $(a,b)$ still the left and right derivative

since $f$ is differentiable on $I$ or $a\in I$ then $f$ is differentiable at $a$ and thus

$f$ is right differentiable at $a$
the same for the left differentiable at $b$

To prove other direction

i'm stuck i don't know how to make proof
any help would be apperciated

Comment: Can you prove the direction $\implies$? **Edit:** it should be "forall $a,b\in I$ with $a<b$".

Comment: For the other direction, note that $I = \cup_{a,b \in I} [a,b]$.

Comment: What about the function $f$ with $f(x)=\chi_{[a,b]}(x)$? It is differentiable (constant, even) on the subinterval, but has jump discontinuities at the endpoints.

Comment: could you post detailed solution i can't make it

Comment: Consider the different possible forms that $I$ can take: $[c,d[, ]c,d[,]-\infty, d[$, etc. (...)

Comment: (...) For instance in the case where $I=]c,d]$ for some real numbers $c,d$ with $c<d$, start by taking an arbitrary element $x_0\in I$. You wish to prove that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ knowing that it's differentiable at $f_{|[a,b]}$ for all $a,b\in$ with $a<b$. Necessarily $c\leq x_0<d$. If $c=x_0$, you're done by applying the hypothesis on $[x_0,x_0+\varepsilon[$(for a sufficiently small $\varepsilon$ which you can explicitly find). If $c<x_0$, then there exists $\delta>0$ such that $[x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta]\subset I$ and you can apply the hypothesis on $[x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta]$.

Comment: If that is a counterexample, it should make one of the sides of $\iff$ true and the other false. Which is true and which is false?

Comment: @GitGud you have good reasoning could you post ur solution

Comment: @Educ Someone already did, the only difference being that Zang only considered points on the interior of $I$. For the end points you need to discuss it case wise as I explained.

Answer (score 0):

We only need to show $f$ is differentiable at each $x\in I$.

For interior point $x\in I$, then $\exists [a,b]\subset I$ such that $x\in[a,b]$, then we apply the assumption.

If $x$ is end point of the interval, say the left endpoint, then just consider $[x,b]\subset I$.

Comment: @GitGud Sorry, I mean $\exists [a,b]\subset I$, such that $x\in[a,b]$.

Comment: what about the end points you didn't discuss it

Comment: @Educ I think it should be clear for the endpoint, since $I$ can't be a single point.

Comment: sorry i prefer only the detailed answer